# Web site looks different after content db addition to a different farm

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, content-database

I backed up a content db from our production MOSS 2007 farm and then I added to an existing web application to the recovery wss 3.0 farm. However after doing it, the root site from the new db's site collection has a different appearance: there is just plain html and none of the links will open.

Here is a picture of the problem:

What could be causing this?

[image: plain html image]

EDIT: The following error is displayed while opening a list/library on a page:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'beyond application level. This error can be caused      by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\template\layouts\web.config line 244)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following web.config file on http://goo.gl/7GHu1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation batch="false" batchTimeout="600" maxBatchSize="10000" 
maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="10000" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory, 
System.Web, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
   </system.web>
  <location path="upload.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ctdmsettings.aspx">
     <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
   <location path="ChangeContentTypeOptionalSettings.aspx">
    <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
   <location path="MngField.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
   <location path="fldpick.aspx">
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" />
     </system.web>
   </location>
   <location path="ManageContentTypeField.aspx">
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" />
     </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Still don't know why this file works, but it does. Now I'm able to see every web page element in a proper way and the libraries open normally.

Comment: This is very bad practice to download a web.config from a third party site. A web.config file is as specific to websites as faces are to humans. If you have multiple backups of a web.config, I would try to restore it.

Comment: I know this can be harmful to my environment, but unfortunately no one ever thought before of backing up things other than content dbs. My need was to recover a folder and this procedure served my purpose. Now I should look more deeply into what the cause might be.

Comment: If anything, I would copy the web.config from the previous farm, and even that isn't great practice.

Answer (score 2):

Your css files have probably been misreferenced, so I would carry over those css files to the new server (assuming that it's a new server)

Your CSS Files can be located from:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES

Also,

1. Is your wss recovery farm the same version as the original?
2. How did you recover (what method) your sharepoint/wss databases?

Comment: I think this is probably it.  The screenshot looks like the style sheets are missing.

Comment: The two farms are at the same service pack level (SP2). I recovered the database by:

1. Getting it from our backup media.
2. Adding it to our recovery farm SQL Server.
3. Attaching it to wss by issuing stsadm -o addcontentdb over an existing web app.